# Ajax doesn't send form data to my PHP file to send mail

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

I'm trying to make a contact form using Ajax and PHPMailer.

I already managed to send a mail with my html form and my php file; however, I'd like to use Ajax to prevent the page from reloading and display a popup telling the user if the mail was sent or not. 
When I try to submit the form, nothing happens and when I remove the event parameter in my JQuery function, the page loads forever.

I tried displaying the popup without including Ajax in my js file and it worked fine, so I assume the JQuery libraries are imported correctly and the problem is that Ajax doesn't send my from data to my php file.

My HTML form:

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="traitement-formulaire.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Nom</label>
                      <input type="text" name="nom" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre nom" id="nom">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Prénom</label>
                      <input type="text" name="prenom" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre prénom" id="prenom">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Adresse mail</label>
                  <input type="text" name="mail" class="form-control" id=" mail formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="ex.: exemple@gmail.com">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Sujet</label>
                  <input type="text" name="sujet" class="form-control" id=" sujet formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Objet de votre demande">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Votre message</label>
                  <textarea type="text" name="message" class="form-control" id=" message formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Détaillez votre demande ici..."></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-actions">
                  <button class="submit-form btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Envoyer</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

My JQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#contact').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: 'traitement-formulaire.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#contact').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('.alert-success').css('display', 'block');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.alert-success').css('display' , 'none');
                $('#nom').val("");
                $('#prenom').val("");
                $('#mail').val("");
                $('sujet').val("");
                $('#message').val("")
            }, 3000);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            $('.alert-danger').css('display', 'block');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.alert-danger').css('display' , 'none');
                $('#nom').val("");
                $('#prenom').val("");
                $('#mail').val("");
                $('#sujet').val("");
                $('#message').val("")
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
});
```

});

My PHP file:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$nom = trim($_POST['nom']);
$prenom = trim($_POST['prenom']);
$mail = trim($_POST['mail']);
$sujet = trim($_POST['sujet']);
$message = trim($_POST['message']);

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'ns0.ovh.net';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'postmaster@sp-neo.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '*************';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($mail, $nom);
    $mail->addAddress('contact@sp-neo.com');     // Add a recipient
    //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    //$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    // Attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $sujet;
    $mail->Body    = $message;
    //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    header( 'Location: index.html' );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

?>

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

HTML Code for popups:

```
  <!--Alert-->
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="popup-success">
      Votre message a bien été envoyé.
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="popup-error">
      Erreur: Votre message n'a pas pu être envoyé.
  </div>
  <!--Alert-->
```

CSS code for popups:

```
#popup-success{
display: none;
}
#popup-error{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: _“so I assume”_ - don’t assume; _verify_ what actually happens. Your browser dev tools network panel can easily show you whether a request is being made or not. And you can easily debug into your JS code as well - so do that, and figure out what is actually going on.

Comment: can you please share the what error you are facing?

Comment: I followed your advice and looked at the Console on Firefox and got this error: TypeError: $.ajax is not a functionmain.js:4:11
    <anonymous> http://localhost/js/main.js:4
    jQuery 2

Comment: Looks like you either load jQuery after your script or you have slim version of jQuery loaded

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue! Now I'm facing another problem, Ajax returned me an error so I looked up at the Network tool. The POST request was indeed sent but the error I got is 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Then you have a php error somewhere. Check you php logs for the error message

Comment: I checked my php error logs file and found this: [Thu Aug 29 15:51:54.918695 2019] [php7:error] [pid 17140] [client 127.0.0.1:49590] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/traitement-formulaire.php on line 5, referer: http://localhost/

Comment: Looks like the path to the PHPMailer files is wrong. Did you install it using composer?

Comment: That was the issue, thank you! However, I still get an error: 
`[Thu Aug 29 16:03:08.868613 2019] [php7:warn] [pid 25841] [client 127.0.0.1:49914] PHP Warning:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/html/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 1162, referer: http://localhost/`

Comment: I just fixed the issue: my $mail string was in conflict with the PHPMailer $mail so I renamed it to $email instead. The mail was successfully sent, however the "error" popup was displayed instead of the "success" one.
I looked it up and found out that I have to return JSON from my php file

Comment: Can you update your question to incude the alert elements too?

Comment: remove `header( 'Location: index.html' );` as it doesn't do anyrthing. Change `dataType: 'JSON',` to `dataType: 'text',` and add `echo "mail sent";` after `$mail->send();`

Comment: This solves the issue, thanks a lot! Everything runs fine now.

Comment: Gald i could help you. I updated the answer to include that too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an answer so people who may have the same problems shouldn't look through the comments.

You first problem was that you where either using slim jQuery or you had jQuery to load after your script.

Then the paths to you PHPMailer files was wrong.

Lastly you read the mail from the form and add it to `$mail` variable

`$mail = trim($_POST['mail']);`

but then you initiallize the PHPMailer object on the same variable

`$mail = new PHPMailer(true);`

Change

`$mail = trim($_POST['mail']);`

to something like

`$sender = trim($_POST['mail']);`

and also change this line

`$mail->setFrom($mail, $nom);`

to

`$mail->setFrom($sender, $nom);`

Finally you have `dataType: 'JSON',` but your script doesn't respond with a JSON

You should change that to `dataType: 'text',` and add `echo "mail sent";` after `$mail->send();`

Also remove `header( 'Location: index.html' );` as it doesn't do something.